# Deixar alguns input select multiple(Angular Material) pre marcados

Tags: html, json, angular, input, material

Eu estou usando Angular Material em minha aplicação, e ela por sua vez tem essa lista criada para preencher meu input:

```
lista: any[] = [
{
  name: 'Cursos',
  tribunais: [
    { value: 'RDC1'},
    { value: 'RDC2'},
    { value: 'RDC3'},
    { value: 'RDC4'},
    { value: 'RDC5'},
    { value: 'INF' }
  ]
}
]
```

E eu tenho o meu componente HTML, que renderiza essa lista:

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select placeholder="Cursos" multiple>
  <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of lista" [label]="group.name" [disabled]="group.disabled">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let tribunais of group.tribunais" [value]="tribunais.value">
    {{tribunais.value}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-optgroup>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

E ele fica visualmente assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem eu quero deixar alguns inputs pre marcados quando eu inicio meu componente, como eu faço para deixar marcado algumas opçao pre definidas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim como citado na [documentação](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api), você pode criar uma lista com os resultados e já pode colocar os valores do `value` incluidos nessa lista.

```
public selecionados = [RDC1, RDC4];
```

e depois fazer o binding, conexão do dados com o html, da lista criada

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selecionados " ...>
</mat-select>
```

**Update:**

```
public selecionados = ['RDC1', 'RDC4'];
```

Adicione aspas simples, aos items da lista, pois a lista resultante deve ser de `string`, já que os valores de cada item selecionado também é uma `string`.
Eu fiz um exemplo no [stackbliz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiselect-material)

**UPpdate 2:**

Para analisar o valores de selecionados

```
{{ selecionados | json }}
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selecionados " ...>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Eu tentei, simplesmente nao funciona assim

Comment: @MarceloHenriqueDosReis tenta da nova maneira

Comment: tambem nao deu, acho que e pq existe um for dentro de outro, e ele nao consegue associar o ngModel com o value

Comment: Coloque o o ngModel e o selecionados, depois insere a interpolação no html `{{ selecionado | json }}` para você analisar o conteudo dos selecionados. Assim você saberá corretamente os valores de cada `select`.

Comment: assim: [(ngModel)]="{{ selecionado | json }}" ?, pq eu tentei e deu erro no angular

Comment: Não. use o ngModel como eu fiz na resposta. o `{{ selecionado | json }}` você vai adicionar no seu código HTML assim como vc fez com o `tribunais.value`. porem vc vai colocar ele em cima do `mat-form-field`

Comment: Não entendi a explicação, pode fazer um update no codigo para eu entender melhor?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89990/discussion-between-victor-henrique-and-marcelo-henrique-dos-reis).